# How do flight arrows affect ranged damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack

I'd like to clarify how flight arrows work in Pathfinder:

> Benefit: A flight arrows range increment is 20 feet greater with longbows, 10 feet greater with shortbows.
>
> Drawback: Flight arrows deal damage as if one size category smaller.

I'm assuming this drawback applies to the size category of the bow damage? So a medium longbow now deals 1d6 damage instead of 1d8? I'm basing this off the description of Gravity Bow which says it increases the size and weight of the arrows or bolts fired from the bows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is indeed correct, the arrow does damage as though the bow was one size smaller.

Comment: Do you have a cite for this? Or a reasoning that supports it? A single sentence isn't much of an answer

Comment: I agree the wording of the spell could have been better which was why I asked the question. The wording of the spell for Gravity Bow does seem to support this mechanic though. Also there doesn't seem to be any other sensible interpretation.

Comment: The description of the item, as posted by Chris, states 'Flight arrows deal damage as if one size category smaller'  </br> While the wording is not ideal, there has never been an errata or FAQ concerning this item.  The wording is self explanatory, really.

Comment: @HL971: I think the confusion is over the fact that one sentence refers to the _arrows_ damage, and the other refers to the _bows_ damage, and there's concern about if these refer to the same thing.

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Ideally they would have written the drawback as "flight arrows deal damage as if fired from a bow one size category smaller".